# Updating users with different descriptions in AD

Tags: powershell

I have a .csv file with a couple of users and each user has a different description.  I'm trying to create a script to update the users' description with what is in the .csv file.  I have searched but have been unable to find a script that does what I need it to do.  Can someone take a look at my script please?  I am erroring at: 
Unexpected token 'in' in expression or statement. At line:6 char:35 
Unexpected token 'in' in expression or statement. At line:6 char:38

```
ipmo ac*
$file = c:\user_file.csv
$user = $_.samaccountname
$desc = $_.description

Import-csv $file | Foreach ($user in $file) {
@(Set-aduser -identity $($file.user) -description $($file.desc))
}
```

Any help would be appreciated since I have been trying to do this for a week now and I'm sure it's something easy?

Comment: It should just be `Set-aduser -identity $user.samaccountname -description $user.description` assuming samaccountname  and description were column names in that file.  Not sure what you were trying to do with `$user` and `$desc`. They would have been null. Also you are using `foreach` incorrectly.

Answer (score 1):

I would instead do something like this.

```
ipmo ac*
$file = "c:\user_file.csv"
Import-csv $file | ForEach-Object{
    Set-aduser -identity $_.samaccountname -description $_.description
}
```

This is assuming you have your CSV with columns called `samaccountname` and `description`.

Not sure what you were trying to do with `$user` and `$desc` so those are just omitted. Guessing they would have actually been null since `$_` is meant to be used inside a pipeline.

The `ForEach` you were using is not meant to have pipeline input. The way you have it usually stands on its own. So we switched it to the `ForEach-Object` version that allows pipeline input.

Comment: Error received: 
Set-ADUser : Cannot find an object with identity: '' under:      'DC=test,DC=net'.
At line:4 char:15
+     Set-aduser <<<<  -identity $_.samaccountname -description $_.description
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (:ADUser) [Set-ADUser], ADIdentityNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Cannot find an object with identity: '' under: 'DC=test,DC=net'.,Microsoft.ActiveDirectory.Management.Commands.SetADUser
   my file contains: 
   SamAccountName,Description 
   user1,"Alumni, 1234567"
   user2,"Alumni, 2345678"
   user3,"Alumni, 3456789

Comment: @priara I want to know what the first 3 lines of you CSV look like now... oh you have it. Can you add it to your question.

Comment: This is what it looks like:

SamAccountName,Description
user1,"Alumni, 1234567"
user2,"Alumni, 2345678"
user3,"Alumni, 3456789"

Comment: My first guess in your CSV has an error in it. It looks like `$_.SamAccountName` is null. Wonder if the column header or data has spaces or something that you can't see. Code should work as is. Try creating another CSV sample maybe. Or just check that the `Import-csv $file` works correctly.

Comment: THANK YOU SO MUCH!  There was a space after the word "Description" in the header.  I just ran the script against 5 test users and it worked.  Ugh... I spent over a week researching and re-writing the script to no avail.  Thank you again!!!

Comment: @priara No problem. I live for this stuff